# More information on SQL error

Tags: sql, csv, mariadb

I'm trying to import a CSV file into a table of my database, however I'm getting an error.

Here is the query :

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/shr/transfers.txt' INTO TABLE transfers 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
IGNORE 1 LINES 
(from_stop_id, to_stop_id, @dummy, transfer_time);
```

However it raises me the following error :

> ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`reseau_ratp`.`transfers`, CONSTRAINT `fk_tsi` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`to_stop_id`) REFERENCES `stops` (`stop_id`))

Is there any way I can get the line of the `.txt` file where this query is failing ?

Comment: Your problem would appear to be in the data, not in the query. It's telling you that some of the data you're importing is violating a foreign key constraint.

Comment: @MattThrower : Yes, but I'm pretty much sure that there are no problems in the data, which is why I would like to get the line of the `.txt` where the query is failing, because I guess that is a formating problem or something.

Comment: Can you disable or drop FK constraints in MariaDB? Then you could import it all and run a query to find the offending rows.

Comment: Well indeed, some rows are causing problems. Is there any way I can ignore them during import ? (I mean, not importing them)

Comment: Well, If anyone interested, I managed to do this using a table with no constraints, using `DELETE [...] WHERE [...]` statement and using `INSERT` then.